# incrementing elements of a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, increment

It is about 10 motivation stories where i have to "grade" them by looking at several aspects. The first if statement checks if the length of the story is more then 280 characters, the second if statement checks if the first letter is a capital letter. I want to store the scores in `candidscore` so if candid 2 has a length > 280 and the first letter is a capital one i want the `candidscore[1]` to be 2.

Code:

```
candidscore = numpy.zeros(10)

for i in range(0, 9):
    if lengthmot[i] > 280:
        candidscore[i] =+ 1
    if lengthmot[i] > 0:
        if motivation[i][0].isupper():    
            candidscore[i] =+ 1
```

problem:
The array `candidscore` does initialy look like: `array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])`  so that works.

It checks if the length > 280, this works to and the array has several ones in it. `array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.])`. So this works as well

Then it should checks if the first letter is a capital letter, I think it does check it but it only increments the score where it is still 0 after the first if statement so it looks like this:  `array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.])`.

However according to the data it should/i want it to look like this:
`array([ 2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  2.])`.

I do not understand why the elements which are already 1 do not increment.

Comment: `=+` does not equal `+=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `=+` instead of `+=`, change that and it should work

Comment: wow thank you such a small error i have been overlooking for days

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer if it currently works.